# Wpf designer cannot apply Style

Tags: wpf, styles, code-behind

In Wpf I inherit from the Button class:

```
public class MenuButton : Button
    {
        public MenuButton()
        {
            this.Style = FindResource("MenuButton") as Style;
        }
        public MenuButton(string caption, ICommand command)
        : this()
    {
        SetValue(ContentProperty, caption);
        this.command = command;
    }
}
```

In a window I added a control

```
<c:MenuButtons x:Name="MenuProject" c:MenuItems="{x:Static d:MenuItems.Project}" />
```

Where c: en d: are my namespaces.
`MenuItems` is a dependencyproperty of usercontrol `MenuButtons` and is declared in a class like:

`public readonly static MenuButton[] Project = new MenuButton[] { new MenuButton("Open", new Command()), ..etc };`

The resource is defined like:

```
 <Style x:Key="MenuButton"
           BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}"
           TargetType="{x:Type c:MenuButton}">
```

The visual studio designer says: 'MenuButton' TargetType does not match type of element 'MenuButton'. The code runs fine, but the designer has trouble invoking the constructor of my MenuButton class. When commenting out that line the error disappears, but then the style is not applied and vice versa.

Comment: Not sure if it's relevant but `this.Style = FindResource("MenuButton") as Style;` shouldn't be in the constructor. you can override `OnApplyTemplate()` method and apply it there.

Comment: That helps! The effect is that the style is applied at run-time not at design-time, at least there is no error. Why is the style not allowed in the constructor?

Comment: Check out Jon's answer to my [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363082/why-does-resources-cannot-be-fetched-in-a-controls-constructor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.Style = FindResource("MenuButton") as Style;` should not appear in the constructor.

You can apply it in the [OnApplyTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.onapplytemplate.aspx) method

```
public overrride OnApplyTemplate()
{
     this.Style = FindResource("MenuButton") as Style;
     base.OnApplyTemplate(); 
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Any idea how to apply the style also at design-time?