# Why does resources cannot be fetched in a control's constructor

Tags: c#, wpf

### Background

I know that fetching resources using [FindResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findresource.aspx) method won't work when done from a control's  constructor as it will always return null.

```
public class MyButton : Button
{
    public MyButton()
    {
        Style = FindResource("myStyle") as Style;
    }
}
```

I know it can be done through the [OnApplyTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.onapplytemplate.aspx) method.

```
public override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
    Style = FindResource("myStyle") as Style;
    base.OnApplyTemplate();
}
```

### Question

Why? I assume it has something to do with the loading of the [VisualTree](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753391.aspx#two_trees) but I was hoping to get a more detailed and accurate answer (or just a correct one incase I'm totally off here) from you WPF experts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because finding the resource most involves either walking the logical element tree (to find resources associated with an ancestor) or looking at the `Resources` of the current element.

In both cases this is not possible unless [`Parent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.parent.aspx) or [`Resources`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.resources.aspx) respectively has already been set to its "correct" value; these are properties and the XAML serialization engine sets them *after* the constructor has run. That is, when you write

```
<Button Height="80" Width="150" />
```

The XAML deserializer ends up doing the equivalent of

```
var button = new Button(); // element is instantiated
button.Height = 80;        // ...and THEN properties are set
button.Width = 150;
```

Therefore, you can't do anything inside the constructor that depends on the properties being set.

To corroborate the above, from the documentation of [`FindResource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findresource.aspx):

> If the resource is not found on the calling element, the parent
>   element in the logical tree is searched next, then the application,
>   then themes, and finally system resources. This lookup methodology is
>   identical to how the tree is searched if a resource were requested by
>   a dynamic resource reference in markup.

Walking the logical tree is of course done through the `Parent` property; this is intuitive but it's also clearly spelled out in the documentation for [`LogicalTreeHelper.GetParent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.logicaltreehelper.getparent.aspx):

> This method is merely a wrapper that gets the appropriate type version
>   (`FrameworkElement` or `FrameworkContentElement`) of the
>   `FrameworkElement.Parent` or `FrameworkContentElement.Parent` property; so
>   unless you are unable to determine the current type, you might want to
>   check the respective instance properties instead.